# corrplot.mixed plot is being cut off in r notebook

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I've just updated my packages due to an error in R and now, when I plotted my corrplot.mixed plot, it will not display correctly (the top of the plot is cut off):

[image]

The code I've used to generate the plot is exactly the same as I was using previously:

```
corrplot.mixed(data, number.cex=0.3, tl.cex=0.4)
```

Also, when I built the plot previously, many of the smaller correlation values where much fainter, making the plot less cluttered - now, even the really small values are visible as well.  I'm not sure what has happened but is there a way to get the plot to display correctly in the R notebook?

I had the issue also with some ACF/PACF plots which I managed to get around using the following code:

```
par(mar=c(3,3,3,3))
```

I tried this but it doesn't work in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by changing the code to the following:

```
corrplot.mixed(data, number.cex = 0.4, tl.cex=0.5, tl.pos="l")
```